# Linking two tables from different remote MS Access DB's

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I currently have a site (.net 2.0) with MS Access DB for data, within the access.mdb are 2 linked tables from another DB on the same site. - all of my code works fine and all my DB connections point to the one DB. I have a need now to achieve the same results, but don't want to create the links in the live DB. How can the same results be achieved via another method?

I looked at an example from: [Syntax for Import Into from Different DBs - MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918605/syntax-for-import-into-from-different-dbs-ms-access)

My tables are large and don't think this is fastest way, I would think two connections and working with tables would be better, but I'm open to a proper way to accomplish this.

Here is my web.conf file with connections to the one DB.

```
<connectionStrings>
<clear />
<add name="OdbcServices" connectionString="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=e:\LeaveDB.mdb;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My end result I need to join 2 tables from different DB's something like:

```
SELECT username.table1, password.table1, fullname.table2 FROM Table1 INNER JOIN [;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.mdb].Table2 ON username.table1 = username.table2;
```

Comment: If you import the data via a query, it is a one time deal is it not?  In that case, it doesnt matter how much data there is.

Comment: I suppose your right, would you happen to have an example with proper syntax? I can't seem to figure out the linking and joining of the two tables in vb.net Do I import the table as a new table then do existing  querys and then drop table?

Comment: that is correct, I'm looking to have one query that gets tables from two different databases

Comment: I have linked tables in a database, and that is the end result, but I need to accomplish the same results in code and not via linked tables within the DB.

Comment: No thats the problem, not any more, and they are live so I would have to take one down to modify links

Comment: Even via code you will run into the moment when you need to drop the linked table and rename the newly imported one which wont work with connections open on it.

Comment: I didn't think about that... so how about just linking to the two tables and running one query? again I'm not sure of the syntax

Comment: if you leave the 2 'external' tables linked/attached they will look and act like local physical tables, so not sure I understand the question.  the only real problem with linked/attached tables is that the physical DB could move or get renamed causing the link to break.

Comment: sorry, I have 2 DB's that are not linked... I need to link them in code within the query or some other way.

Comment: I have refreshed links in code, never created them.  see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3251513/1070452  and also http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/370859-create-linked-table-access  Then you have to (presumably) issue new code to use the new schema.  All in all, it seems better to plan out and have things ready, then shut things down for an hour to reconfig everything.  The only site that never seems to go sown for main or upgrades is Google, so it is not unheard of.

Comment: ok, that sounds like the solution, now I just need to figure out how to do it in vb.net in aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than create an "official" linked table (TableDef object) you might get away with simply creating a View that points to the table in the other database. I just tried this in C# and it seemed to work fine:

```csharp
string myConnectionString;
myConnectionString =
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        @"Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;";

using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    con.Open();

    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = 
                @"CREATE VIEW otherTable AS " +
                @"SELECT * FROM [;Database=C:\__tmp\main.accdb].otherTable";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

That creates a "View" (saved query in Access) that seems to work just like a linked table.

Comment: This is great, the query did the trick, only issue I can't seem to find is how to DROP a query I create with this script? all my searches seem to point to Queries that delete records?

Comment: actually I just did the DROP otherTable and that worked since I didn't have a TABLE with the same name as the QUERY (VIEW) - Will the DROP VIEW work on just the QUERY?

Comment: @BarclayVision Yes, `DROP VIEW` should only affect saved queries. (Besides, you can't have a Table and a Query with exactly the same name in the same Access database.)